# How to mock GCP's storage in golang?

Tags: go, mocking

I'm really new to mocking third-party library in go, I'm mocking `cloud.google.com/go/storage` right now

I'm using [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery). This is my current interface:

```
//Client storage client
type Client interface {
    Bucket(name string) BucketHandle
    Buckets(ctx context.Context, projectID string) BucketIterator
}

//BucketHandle storage's BucketHandle
type BucketHandle interface {
    Attrs(context.Context) (*storage.BucketAttrs, error)
    Objects(context.Context, *storage.Query) ObjectIterator
}

//ObjectIterator storage's ObjectIterator
type ObjectIterator interface {
    Next() (*storage.ObjectAttrs, error)
}

//BucketIterator storage's BucketIterator
type BucketIterator interface {
    Next() (*storage.BucketAttrs, error)
}
```

and this is how I use it in my function

```
//Runner runner for this module
type Runner struct {
    StorageClient stiface.Client
}

.... function
   //get storage client
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    runner := Runner{
        StorageClient: client,
    }
.... rest of functions
```

However, I got this error:

> cannot use client (type *"cloud.google.com/go/storage".Client) as type stiface.Client in field value:
>       *"cloud.google.com/go/storage".Client does not implement stiface.Client (wrong type for Bucket method)
>           have Bucket(string) *"cloud.google.com/go/storage".BucketHandle
>           want Bucket(string) stiface.BucketHandle

What have I done wrong here? Thanks!

**Edit**

here's one example of the code that I want to mock. I'd like to mock on `bucketIterator.Next()`:

```
//GetBuckets get list of buckets
func GetBuckets(ctx context.Context, client *storage.Client, projectName string) []checker.Resource {
    //Get bucket iterator based on a project
    bucketIterator := client.Buckets(ctx, projectName)
    //iterate over the buckets and store bucket details
    buckets := make([]checker.Resource, 0)
    for bucket, done := bucketIterator.Next(); done == nil; bucket, done = bucketIterator.Next() {
        buckets = append(buckets, checker.Resource{
            Name: bucket.Name,
            Type: "Bucket",
        })
    }
    return buckets
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, the way you'd use stiface is as below

If you need to mock `stiface.BucketIterator`, you can create a mock as

```golang
type mockBucketIterator struct {
    stiface.BucketIterator
}
```

and mock the `Next` accordingly

```golang
func (m mockBucketIterator) Next() (*storage.BucketAttrs, error) {
    // mocks that you need this to return
    return
}
```

You could use the same method to mock all the way up to `satiface.Client` and feed the mock client to your test.

For reference, a full example in my tests:

```golang
type clientMock struct {
    stiface.Client
}
type bucketMock struct {
    stiface.BucketHandle
}
type objectItMock struct {
    stiface.ObjectIterator
    i    int
    next []storage.ObjectAttrs
}

func (m clientMock) Bucket(name string) stiface.BucketHandle {
    return bucketMock{}
}
```

and then the object iterator to return mocked iterator as well

```golang
func (it *objectItMock) Next() (a *storage.ObjectAttrs, err error) {
    if it.i == len(it.next) {
        err = iterator.Done
        return
    }

    a = &it.next[it.i]
    it.i += 1
    return
}

func (m bucketMock) Objects(ctx context.Context, q *storage.Query) (it stiface.ObjectIterator) {
    it = &objectItMock{
        i: 0,
        next: []storage.ObjectAttrs{
            {Name: "abc"},
            {Name: "def"},
            {Name: "ghi"},
        },
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is basically saying your `stiface.Client` defines an interface that `*storage.Client` does not implement. On first glance your code looks valid however the problem lies in your interface method signatures and because they have outputs as interfaces.

Go makes a difference between the statements:

- This function returns a `BucketHandle`
- and this function returns a `*storage.BucketHandle` that is a `BucketHandle`

Try changing your interface to return the `*storage.BucketHandle`. You can see a more complex example of similar behaviour in the [mockery `S3API` example](https://github.com/jaytaylor/mockery-example/blob/master/mocks/S3API.go) where the functions return the `s3` types, not their own interfaces.

Comment: But if I return the actual struct, how can I mock the function in the inner struct? e.g. I want to mock `Next()` in `client.Buckets(ctx, projectName).Next()`. I've made an edit to the question so it includes the code I want to test

Comment: have the same question